# Locked Accounts

Tags: facebook

My boyfriend's Facebook account has been locked due to someone compromising his account and he doesn't have any form of ID to turn in. How do we get his account unlocked?

Comment: try to contact the [Facebook support](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=220217228006012)

Answer (score 1):

As JMax said, contact Facebook via one of their forms. There is not much we can do. We are not official Facebook support so we cannot ask Facebook to do anything on your behalf.